# Django rest framework Anonymous user is always Authenticated

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, anonymous-users

I'm trying to authenticate my web API method using django rest framework isauthenticated permission and TokenAuthentication
The API method:

```
@api_view(['Post'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def listofgroups(request):
    try:
        logout(request)
        data = request.data
        page_size = data.get('pagesize')
        page_number = data.get('pagenumber')
        group_qs = Group.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(group_qs, int(page_size))
        group_list = paginator.page(int(page_number))
        #group_list = tools.paginate_query_set(group_qs, 1, 3)
        #list  = group_list[0]['model']
        groups = [get_group_dto(g) for g in group_list]
        sorted_groups = sorted(groups, key=lambda k: k['user_count'], reverse = True)
        group_list_dto = {
        "grps": sorted_groups, 
        "success":1,
        "fail":0
        }
        return Response(group_list_dto)
    except Exception as e:
        #.error("Error %s"(e), exc_info = 1) 
        return Response({"success" : 0, "error": str(e)})
```

Basically i should always set Authorization in the header like :

> "Authorization":"Token a26171d30745cc94bcd6ac42d9bc94e1d3992948"

this token is based on rest_framework.authtoken

The Error is that I can get the data with response 200 without even setting the Token in the header because its returning anonymous user which is authenticated from the back end in django.

> How can I prevent anonymous users from being authenticated and return 403 response error for them using django rest framework

I appreciate any help

Comment: what are the facts about your asserts ?I checked several times so far and anonymous users will fail IsAuthenticated. Most likely you are logged with the sessions.

Comment: 1.  You shoud paste your logout function code.

Comment: @Linovia I think you are right i think also i'm logged in with sessions is there anyway that i can kill this session and is there a way to prevent anonymous users from calling this api ??

Comment: @Hayden I don't have a login and logout functions i'm using token based authentication in django rest framework but the sessions are always enabled in django

Comment: no, they are enabled because the default uses them. Tune your DRF settings to get rid of them for the API part and enjoy

Comment: How can I do that can you give me an example please thank you alot @Linovia

Comment: It should be in the authentication part of the DRF documentation.

Comment: @Linovia it is not working i'm stuck in this, i posted before this issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677952/django-rest-framework-isauthenticated-permission-error-anonymous-user) and got no answer and still have not solved it any help in it please ?

Comment: sry i mean this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47677952/django-rest-framework-isauthenticated-permission-error-anonymous-user)

Comment: dunno, shouldn't be an issue by the look of it.

Comment: If you use the token auth you mentioned above，you must  enable the tokenauth in DRF settings. the session auth is mainly for same domain spa webapp

Comment: Thank you @Hayden but i'm setting it in DRF and its working fine on isAdminuser permission and not working on isauthenticated  permission since anonymous user is always authenticated dont know why

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many classes defined in django rest framework for validation purposes. What I guess in your case is that you will need the following set of decorators:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((TokenAuthentication,))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
```

Considering you have set the header properly it wont be a problem with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

you can this do,

to stay safe and always ask the user for a token, and you don't need to call permission_classes, it will automatically be isAuthenticated

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ]
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
```